# Saving a variable to a .txt file in PHP?

Tags: php, file-io

I am attempting to append a variable to a seperate txt file inside the same directory. However I am having issues having the actual data get written into txt file. By the looks of it, I have the syntax of the commands correct, but the data is not being saved into the file. This is the code I have come up with.

```
$results = "results.txt";
$resultsLink = fopen($results, 'a');
$fileParagraph = $paragraph;
fwrite($resultsLink, $fileParagraph);
fclose($resultsLink);
```

I have created a seperate file under the same directory named "results.txt", and this page is remaining unaffected. $paragraph only contains a string that the user entered from an html page. Any assistance with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should check the return value of your `fopen` call. Might be failing due to permissions, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these things:

1) Have you tried `file_get_content()`'s cousin?
`file_put_contents($results, $fileParagraph, FILE_APPEND);`

This awesome function will do all of that file writing stuff in 1 line.

2)  Check permissions of your file. If using linux, you can allow everyone to read and write to it by setting the permissions to 777.

```
chmod 777 results.txt
```

3) If none of those work, you can check your error logs or enable error reporting if testing locally. PHP should let you know what the deal's all about.

Good luck finding a solution!

Comment: Thank you for your reply, originally I applied the chmod 755 results.txt command, I just applied the fix. I will test both commands on the program and see what happens(it takes a little bit for the commands to take affect on this server).

Comment: Code works perfect, just needed to wait for the server to update the permissions. Thank you for your help Brixster!